# Understanding the app instance of dialogflow service from actions-on-google module

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

How does the POST request happens on an express app using the dialogflow service from actions-on-google nodejs client library ? Does it handle the POST request from Actions on Google internally when I am specifically asking my express app to use the dialogflow app instance ?

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google')
const app = dialogflow()
// HOW DOES IT HANDLE THE POST REQUEST ?
express().use(bodyParser.json(), app).listen(3000)
```

The other approach given in the docs https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview to host as an express app makes more sense as we are actually posting the data to an endpoint:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// ... app code here
const expressApp = express().use(bodyParser.json());
expressApp.post('/fulfillment', app);
expressApp.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Where do you get the first chunk of code from, and why do you think this way is supposed to work?

Comment: In the docs only. The link that I provided above. I think this way because its mentioned that the app instance acts as a handler for HTTP requests and understands the service's specific protocol. That's where I am not exactly sure that how is the POST request is handled in the first case.